# Nodejs 0.12.0 install phonegap on window8

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm Using Windows 8 with nodejs v 0.12.0 when using the following command to download Phonegap

npm install -g phonegap

I'm Getting following error

npm ERR! registry error parsing json

I have already install python 2.7 and java jdk; also all path are set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Use following command and then install phonegap,

```
npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Then add force flag to install it,

```
sudo npm install -gf phonegap
```

Comment: After following line nothing is happening Problem still same...
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
\

Comment: In case you get this error "Error: No compatible version found: phonegap" then add force flag to install it, Please note that I changed to "https://" to go for security. It will work

Comment: Sorry but problem still same . After first line nothing is happening

npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.

Comment: I'm able to phonegap without getting this error, can you please try again? Possible this was something intermittent.

Comment: Which operating system are you using?
I am using WIndows 8

Comment: Windows 8.1 pro. Followed http://phonegap.com/install/ and https://www.npmjs.com/package/phonegap

Comment: with node js v 0.12.0 following message showing with error
npm WARN using --force I sure hope you know what you are doing.
npm WARN engine npm@1.4.28: wanted: {"node":">=0.8","npm":"1"} (current: {"node"
:null,"npm":"2.5.1"})
npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Comment: when use node js  v 0.8.0
it show this error at the end
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\PrakashEnthu\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0